# Log of files created when .exe is run?

Tags: windows-10

I would like to find a list of all the files created (or modified?) when I install a particular program on my Windows 10 computer. Does such a thing exist? Is there a system log that is created, or is this a third party software?

Answer (score 2):

Windows does not do this.

It is up to the application vendor to create logs if it needs to retain logs.

Of my applications here, only a few retain permanent logs or configurations.

Most logs end up here: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp  and are deleted by Disk Cleanup over time or newer Windows 10 storage time settings